# C# Saving all Users input into some kind of database or smth

Tags: c#

I have just started programming C# codes and I'm enjoying typing my own little windows form app.

Screenshots:

[image: One of four tabs]

[image: One of four tabs]

Its written in C#. It basically takes an user Input, called "Kassenbestand", - "Ausgaben" + "Einnahmen" and gives out an calculated € value at "End Bestand". So very simple.

I have got two questions:

First:

I would like to create a button to save ALL the input he does, so he can save and open it afterwords, in case he forgot something.

As i wrote, I'm very new, so what do i have to do. I saw a lot of stuff with database etc. but maybe one of you professionals can support me better and explain me ? :)

Second question:

I wrote an saving function, to make an screenshot so he can print out all the stuff he wants. But he needs to cut off useless borders etc. Is there a smoother way to capture the Form and print it out? I read a lot of `PrintDocument` function etc. Any tips ?

Comment: You can attach the screenshots here itself.

Comment: It's really too broad

Comment: I used the menu to upload the screenshots here, sorry, new user here :p

Comment: i simply want to save all values, the user enteres, so be saved, so he can simply click on load values from 23.02.1203 and all the values are at the same boxes again,.

Answer (score 0):

To save your user inputs I would suggest to save them in a .csv-file.

Writing a csv file:

```
        StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Test\kassenbestand.csv");
        string header = "Datum;Kassenbestand;Ausgaben;Einnahmen";
        sw.WriteLine(header);
        //Write your Data
        string line = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3}", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(), 550, 400, 600);
        //...
        //...
        //...
        sw.Close();
```

Reading a csv file:

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Test\kassenbestand.csv");
        sr.ReadLine();//skip the header
        while (sr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string line1 = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] splitted = line1.Split(';');
            // splitted[0] Datum
            // splitted[1] Kassenbestand
            // ...
        }
        sr.Close();
```

For taking a screenshot of your window you can use this function:

```
    private System.Drawing.Bitmap TakeScreenshot()
    {
        int StartX, StartY;
        int Width, Height;
        StartX = 0;
        StartY = 0;
        Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width);
        Height = Convert.ToInt32(this.Height);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap Screenshot = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width, Height);
        System.Drawing.Graphics G = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Screenshot);
        G.CopyFromScreen(StartX, StartY, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height));
        G.Dispose();
        return Screenshot;
    }
```

To save it you only need to save your bitmap:

```
       System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = TakeScreenshot();
       bitmap.Save(@"C:\Test\screenshot.png");
       bitmap.Dispose();
```

Comment: You sir are awesome. Im gonna try to bring my work to life with your help and reply after ive finished.

Comment: Hey there, i see youre from germany. Is there any chance i can contact you on skype or teamspeak?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible.